# Does clang perform const substitution despite -O0?

Tags: c, clang

I'm checking out an example from the book *21st Century C*:

```
// constfusion.c
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *var;
    int const **constptr = &var;
    int const fixed = 20;
    *constptr = &fixed;
    *var = 30;
    printf("fixed = %i, *var = %i\n", fixed, *var);
}
```

It's supposed to output `fixed = 30, *var = 30` illustrating why it is an error to assign `int **` to `const int **`, but instead it outputs `fixed = 20, *var = 30`!

I'm compiling with `clang -O0 constfusion.c -o constfusion`. My setup:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is it the compiler or is it me?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, [the code is not valid](http://ideone.com/Niu1e5).

Comment: undefined behavior behaves in an undefined way. -O0 just means "don't do any extra optimizations", it doesn't mean "do the most naive translation from source to object matching the expectations of the programmer, whatever they may be which is different from programmer to programmer".

Comment: Just as an additional point of data, I am using NI CVI  C compiler, with settings to aggressive/pedantic.  Builds/runs,0 errors/warning, with your stated expected results. (***fixed = 30, *var = 30***)    I ran it twice with same results, once using C99 extensions and once without.  This result shows implementation differences between the different compilers in an area ***[not defined in the C standard](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)***.  It appears that using this for the purpose of  _illustrating why it is an error to assign int ** to const **_ may not be an effective teaching tool.